# JQuery DatePicker background color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an example of JQuery DatePicker from 
[link text](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

on my asp.net page.

But, background color of the datepicker is white.  I am not sure how to change this. (Change to default color)
My asp.net page background page is white, maybe because of that?

Any help would be appereicate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The background formatting for the control comes from the `.ui-widget-content` CSS class. Assuming you only want to apply to the date picker and not other controls you want something like this:

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-widget-content {
    background: #999 none;
}
```

If instead you want to change the background colour for all controls, just find the existing `.ui-widget-content` class in your CSS and change that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am just started to learn JQuery. So, you put that in the <script> section inside of function()?

Comment: No, you add that to a CSS stylesheet. You should have one that came with jquery UI download, just add it to that.

Comment: Ah, got it.  Thanks both of you for help!

Answer (score 3):

Just Add this one line of code into your jquery ui css file

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title select{color: #000;}
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the background color of DatePicker via the CSS file which come with the package. Locate for class selector `.ui-widget-content`, there should be background attribute which you can change to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

with this function you can color the days you want:

```
$("#dater").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 3,   
});
function ColorDay(month, day, year, backgroundColor)
{
    day--;
    $("[onclick*='"+month+","+year+"'] [class*=ui-state-default]").eq(day).css("background",backgroundColor); 

}
```

then to color a day do:

```
ColorDay(6,30,2012,"yellow"); // color July 30, 2012   of yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

How about try this code

```
 a.ui-state-default{
   background-color: red !important;
 }
```