# How to change the date Picker color?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery DatePicker background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278402/jquery-datepicker-background-color)

Am using the folllowing function for pick the date.It was work fine.How to change the datepicker color in jquery?

```
function DateControl(id){       
    $(id).datepicker({            
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Go to http://jqueryui.com/ and create a theme.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To change the background color of datepicker try this

```css
.ui-datepicker {
   background: #333;
   border: 1px solid #555;
   color: #EEE;
}
```

Comment: For that to work, do you need to add - 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

For changing the background of datepicker

```css
.ui-datepicker 
{
    background: #999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way to style your datepicker is via css.
Style your own or use themeroller ( http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ ).